# Splitting text by quotation marks in R

Tags: r

I am looking to split text I have in one column into several columns. The text should be separated by either '," ",' ',' or ",".

I tried using regular epxressions and \" commands, however, those have not worked yet. I could separate the text into columns by commas, however, that creates too many sub-parts.

The data I am dealing with is scraped from Reddit posts. A comment section for one post would look like this:
['She really messed up bringing politics into climate change.... Climate change is a global problem. It should not be mixed with local conflicts.', "> She really messed up bringing politics into climate change\n\nEverything is politics, climate change more than anything. A shift in *policy* is what's climate activists are striving for. It's politics.", 'There are black-and-white political conflicts where taking sides could be safely done (like the Russian invasion of Ukraine, where Fridays for Future aligned with Ukraine), and there are gray-and-gray political topics where taking sides could only lead to division and polarization within the group (like the Israel-Palestine conflict).', 'but climate change has nothing to do with war. She is just splitting the movement', 'Israel-Palestine is really much less gray than what a lot of people are making it out to be. The Palestine people deserves to have their human rights upheld and protected just as any other people on the planet. Israel is very clearly in the process of carrying out ethnic cleansing and genocide against them. They should stop.', 'The war industry is the largest polluter. Working for peace and diplomacy is one of the most effective ways of reducing CO2e emissions.', "The human rights angle is one thing, but the territorial side of the dispute needs to be addressed as well (especially when it comes to Jerusalem). Both sides are currently taking the irredentist approach, which means the fighting won't stop until one of them secures exclusive and uncontested control of the area.","

Expected output would be:
column 1:
['She really messed up bringing politics into climate change.... Climate change is a global problem. It should not be mixed with local conflicts.',"
column 2:
She really messed up bringing politics into climate change\n\nEverything is politics, climate change more than anything. A shift in *policy* is what's climate activists are striving for. It's politics.", '
column 3:
There are black-and-white political conflicts where taking sides could be safely done (like the Russian invasion of Ukraine, where Fridays for Future aligned with Ukraine), and there are gray-and-gray political topics where taking sides could only lead to division and polarization within the group (like the Israel-Palestine conflict).', '
column 4:
but climate change has nothing to do with war. She is just splitting the movement', '
column 5:
Israel-Palestine is really much less gray than what a lot of people are making it out to be. The Palestine people deserves to have their human rights upheld and protected just as any other people on the planet. Israel is very clearly in the process of carrying out ethnic cleansing and genocide against them. They should stop.', '

etc.

I think the code should look something similar to this, but I could not get it working yet:
Newdf <- df %>%
tidyr::separate_rows(comments, sep ="",'")

Comment: Hi Daria. Can you please provide some sample text and expected output?

Comment: @AndreWildberg i have added some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your data

```
chr_vec <- "['She really messed up bringing politics into climate change.... Climate change is a global problem. It should not be mixed with local conflicts.', \"> She really messed up bringing politics into climate change\n\nEverything is politics, climate change more than anything. A shift in policy is what's climate activists are striving for. It's politics.\", 'There are black-and-white political conflicts where taking sides could be safely done (like the Russian invasion of Ukraine, where Fridays for Future aligned with Ukraine), and there are gray-and-gray political topics where taking sides could only lead to division and polarization within the group (like the Israel-Palestine conflict).', 'but climate change has nothing to do with war. She is just splitting the movement', 'Israel-Palestine is really much less gray than what a lot of people are making it out to be. The Palestine people deserves to have their human rights upheld and protected just as any other people on the planet. Israel is very clearly in the process of carrying out ethnic cleansing and genocide against them. They should stop.', 'The war industry is the largest polluter. Working for peace and diplomacy is one of the most effective ways of reducing CO2e emissions.', \"The human rights angle is one thing, but the territorial side of the dispute needs to be addressed as well (especially when it comes to Jerusalem). Both sides are currently taking the irredentist approach, which means the fighting won't stop until one of them secures exclusive and uncontested control of the area.\",\""
```

Using `strsplit` with several split patterns

```
strsplit(chr_vec, "', \"|\", '|', '")
```

results in

```
[[1]]
[1] "['She really messed up bringing politics into climate change.... Climate change is a global problem. It should not be mixed with local conflicts."                                                                                                                                                                                               
[2] "> She really messed up bringing politics into climate change\n\nEverything is politics, climate change more than anything. A shift in policy is what's climate activists are striving for. It's politics."                                                                                                                                       
[3] "There are black-and-white political conflicts where taking sides could be safely done (like the Russian invasion of Ukraine, where Fridays for Future aligned with Ukraine), and there are gray-and-gray political topics where taking sides could only lead to division and polarization within the group (like the Israel-Palestine conflict)."
[4] "but climate change has nothing to do with war. She is just splitting the movement"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[5] "Israel-Palestine is really much less gray than what a lot of people are making it out to be. The Palestine people deserves to have their human rights upheld and protected just as any other people on the planet. Israel is very clearly in the process of carrying out ethnic cleansing and genocide against them. They should stop."          
[6] "The war industry is the largest polluter. Working for peace and diplomacy is one of the most effective ways of reducing CO2e emissions."                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[7] "The human rights angle is one thing, but the territorial side of the dispute needs to be addressed as well (especially when it comes to Jerusalem). Both sides are currently taking the irredentist approach, which means the fighting won't stop until one of them secures exclusive and uncontested control of the area.\",\""
```

You might have to get rid of some braces at the beginning or end of vectors, but I'm not sure if the string really contains them or if they should be removed at all.

##### tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

tibble(chr_vec) %>% 
  mutate(chr_vec = str_split(chr_vec, "', \"|\", '|', '")) %>% 
  unnest(chr_vec)
# A tibble: 7 × 1
  chr_vec                                                                       
  <chr>                                                                         
1 "['She really messed up bringing politics into climate change.... Climate cha…
2 "> She really messed up bringing politics into climate change\n\nEverything i…
3 "There are black-and-white political conflicts where taking sides could be sa…
4 "but climate change has nothing to do with war. She is just splitting the mov…
5 "Israel-Palestine is really much less gray than what a lot of people are maki…
6 "The war industry is the largest polluter. Working for peace and diplomacy is…
7 "The human rights angle is one thing, but the territorial side of the dispute…
```

Result put in columns

```
tibble(chr_vec) %>% 
  mutate(vec = str_split(chr_vec, "', \"|\", '|', '")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(vec, names_sep="")
# A tibble: 1 × 8
  chr_vec                              vec1  vec2  vec3  vec4  vec5  vec6  vec7 
  <chr>                                <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 "['She really messed up bringing po… ['Sh… "> S… Ther… but … Isra… The … "The…
```